# Plot NN regression/similar predicted output for all inputs

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

Can someone explain why the `Fit` line does not match the true label? I do not understand what exactly is happening and where I have a problem in my model.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
input=heat_y_noisy';              %input data 20000x100
input_normalized=input;

output=alphas_optimal;            %output 20000x1



Xtrain=input(1:18000,:);
Ytrain=output(1:18000,1);

Xtest=input(18000:20000,:);
Ytest=output(18001:20000,1);

net = feedforwardnet([30 20 5] , 'traingd');
net.trainParam.epochs=30;
net.layers{end}.transferFcn='logsig';
net = train(net, Xtrain', Ytrain')

%%
ypred=net(Xtest');

label_predicted=ypred(1,1:5)
true_label=Ytest(1:5,1)'
```

and why does the output remains the same for all inputs?

```
label_predicted =

    0.0360    0.0347    0.0349    0.0358    0.0373


true_label =

    0.0279    0.0265    0.0182    0.0176    0.0148
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is logsig ? Why feedforward and not a backpropagation ?

Comment: @amolgoel do you mean that my model does not train?

Comment: may be . I don't see backproagation in network.

Answer (score 0):

Your model has high bias . This means high error on train data, underfitting. You need to increase complexity of model. You can achieve his by increasing The number of nodes in hidden layer, total number of layers .

Comment: ok clear thank you